# cant access web server through local or network

Tags: networking

I have a web server running in my machine, before i can access the web server.
but now if I try to access via my local machine "localhost:8080/" or through network "10.50.x.x:8080/" i cant access the web server. From the browser output it says "page is not available ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED"

i checked the Apache its running fine, i can ping the ip address and firewall is disabled.

thank you for your help guys,

Comment: what does `netcat -z 10.50.x.x 8080` return

Answer (score 2):

`Connection refused` generally indicates that nothing is listening on the relevant IP:Port pair. Check that Apache is listening correctly by examining the output of

```
netstat -tnlp | grep :8080
```

As an aside there is no need to hide addresses in 10/8, they are not directly contactable from the wider internet.